# Quotient structure of sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

I am learning real analysis and $\sigma-$algebra. Since $\sigma-$algebra is quite similar to all structures discussed in algebra (having arrows, substructures, product structures), I'm wondering whether there is a quotient structure for $\sigma-$algebra. I think that's to say we have to define an ''$\sigma-$ideal'' $I$ making $A / I$ is still a $\sigma-$algebra.

I tried to understand the quotient structure from an algebraic perspective, however I failed for having no ideas of the equivalent relation like that in a group. I also tried search on the internet, however I made no progress.

I know little of category theory. So, if you use the language of category theory, can you explain in a more detailed language?

Thanks.

Comment: If $(X, \Sigma)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $Y\subset X$, you could perhaps say that $A\sim B$ iff $A\cap Y = B\cap Y$ for $A, B\in \Sigma$. The quotient would be a $\sigma$-algebra over $Y$.

Comment: So, in this way, one tends to treat the quotient structure as some sort of 'restrictions'? Is this way also work in other quotient structures, like group, vector space, etc.?

Comment: It is only the first idea that came to my mind. You need an equivalence relation that is compatible in some way with the algebraic structure. Here the «algebraic» operations are the set theoretic intersections, unions, etc. Also if you identify an element of the sigma algebra with a characteristic function, you have an algebra of $F_2$-valued functions. In such algebras, the functions that vanish on a subset are an ideal, so it is logical to think of this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try.